# Best way to have a task in python run until timeout

Tags: python, timeout

One of the Python projects I am working on asks for a task to run to completion under a certain time limit. If the time limit is reached before completion, the overall task is terminated.

Initially, I wanted to use a while loop to check the time; however, this would still mean that the time would be checked once through the loop. Is there an optimal way to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you illustrate your question with some minimal example code, ideally using a [mcve]? Like this, the question is quite vague and unlikely to elicit very useful answers, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the runtime at multiple points in the loop (instead of just once per loop), you could write a function to do so.

```
from time import time

start_time = time()
max_runtime = 1000 # maximum runtime in seconds

def end_loop():
    if time()-start_time > max_runtime:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then you can insert this at various points within your loop, like so:

```
while time()-start_time < max_runtime:
    # do some stuff
    if end_loop():
        break

    # do some more stuff
    if end_loop():
        break
```

That way you don't need to wait until the start of the loop before checking the runtime. However, this approach only allows you to check the runtime at finite points in your code, as it is only possible to break the loop when `end_loop()` is called. It is possible that your runtime will exceed the maximum runtime while waiting for the next `end_loop()`.

Comment: what happen if the task takes longer than the max_runtime in the first loop?

Comment: It will break at the first occurrence of `end_loop()`

Comment: not really, it will just get stuck until completition in your `# do some more stuff` block

Comment: You have to pick finite points at which to check the runtime. You could do this at every other line of code, but no matter where you check you won't be able to break the loop at exactly the maximum runtime.

Comment: you should explain all that in the answer, anyway still lack some logit there

Answer (score -1):

```
import time 

# This will set t_end at 5 minutes
t_end = time.time() * (60 * 5)

while time.time() < t_end:
   if (condition):
       break
   else:
       code
```

This is what I use when doing what you described. It'll check the overall time limit as well as break the loop if your task has been completed.

Comment: what happen if the task takes longer than the max_runtime in the first loop?

Comment: The while loop ends and you can handle the logic out of there. This was suggested a skeleton. Flags can be set to check if the task actually completed or the timer just ran up.